# Passing Socket to Thread C

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to make a network system using UDP. I've managed to get it working, but now I want to put the listening part in a separate thread so I can continue with the program without having to wait for messages (it's going to be used for a game).

The problem is that when I pass the socket to the new thread and use it for listening it doesn't work and just receives random input constantly. When I use the exact same code in the method where I initialize the socket, everything works fine.

This works:

```
bool serverUDP() {
WSADATA w;
SOCKET sd;

struct sockaddr_in server, client;
char buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int bytes_received;
int client_length;

/* Open windows connection */
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2)/*0x0101*/, &w) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open Windows connection.\n");
    return false;
}

/* Open a datagram socket */
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create socket.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return false;
}

/* Clear out server struct */
memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

/* Set family and port */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(atoi(DEFAULT_PORT));

server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = 127;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = 0;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = 0;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = 1;

/* Bind address to socket */
if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind name to socket.\n");
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    return false;
}

client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

/* Receive bytes from client */
while (true) {
    bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, buffer, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
    fprintf(stderr,"received: %s\n", buffer);
}

closesocket(sd);
WSACleanup();   

return true;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
bool serverUDP() {
WSADATA w;
SOCKET sd;

struct sockaddr_in server, client;
char buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int bytes_received;
int client_length;

/* Open windows connection */
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2)/*0x0101*/, &w) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open Windows connection.\n");
    return false;
}

/* Open a datagram socket */
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create socket.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return false;
}

/* Clear out server struct */
memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

/* Set family and port */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(atoi(DEFAULT_PORT));

server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = 127;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = 0;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = 0;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = 1;

/* Bind address to socket */
if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind name to socket.\n");
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    return false;
}

_beginthread((void(*)(void*))receiveThread,0,(void *)sd);

closesocket(sd);
WSACleanup();   

return true;
}

void receiveThread(SOCKET sd)
{
struct sockaddr_in client, server;
char buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

int bytes_received;
int client_length;

client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

while (true) {
    bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, buffer, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
    fprintf(stderr,"received: %s\n", buffer);
}
}
```

The second piece of code just spams random input, as though it's constantly receiving some weird message. The, first piece of code waits for a message and continues when it gets one (I've got a client part too).

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,

Maxim Schoemaker

Comment: Answers about passing a ```SOCKET``` as ```void *``` are correct.  Fixing that will solve your immediate problem.  However, there is more wrong with your code.  Your threaded version is *not* receiving random messages.  You aren't checking the value returned in ```bytes_received``` and you are printing uninitialized memory contents from ```buffer```.  In fact, ```bytes_received``` will be ```-1``` and you can query ```GetLastError()``` for more information.  Your code also depends on the sender to terminate the string with a ```\0``` character.  You then pass ```buffer``` to ```printf()```.

Comment: If you treat the contents of ```buffer``` as a string (which you do), it would be better to carefully guarantee that ```buffer``` always contains a string.  That is, ```buffer``` must be NUL-terminated.  Do this with ```buffer[bytes_received]='\0';```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thread closes the socket immediately after starting the other thread.  Therefore the thread no longer has a valid socket handle.

Comment: That makes sense ^^. Is there a way to counter this or should I just initialize the socket in the new thread?

Comment: He's right. remove that: closesocket(sd);
WSACleanup();   or wait for the second thread to return, on linux you'd use pthread_join(), I don't know about windows.

Comment: @MaximSchoemaker: From a modularity standpoint, my opinion is that the thread that needs/uses the socket should create it.  To "fix" it without doing that, you would need to move the close of the socket to the thread, but creating it in one thread and closing it in another is probably asking for troubles down the road.

Comment: Oh wait. I'm the one closing it :P this is pretty stupid xD Thanks again!

Comment: @MaximSchoemaker 'creating it in one thread and closing it in another' is just about normal in multithreaded apps.  I'm afraid that many classic 'rules of good design' just don't apply to intercommunicating threads. Many actually cause disasters - there are numerous posts where objects are created on stacks and then queued off to threads, so causing the object to be destroyed in the caller before it is processed in the target thread.  Another is 'always use references instead of pointers' - a rule which, if followed, prevents efficient inter-thread comms because refs cannot be reseated.

Answer (score 3):

The source of your problem is this line:

```
_beginthread((void(*)(void*))receiveThread,0,(void *)sd);
```

Basically, you're calling the `receiveThread()` function with the wrong arguments, but you've tricked the compiler into a situation where it cannot detect the error: you're casting the function to the wrong signature and casting the parameter to the wrong type.

Change the `receiveThread()` function so that it has the proper signature, then remove the cast.

```
void * receiveThread(void * context);

_beginthread(receiveThread,0,(void *)sd);
```

Then, pass a pointer to your `sd` variable and deference it in the thread function:

```
_beginthread(receiveThread,0,&sd);


void * receiveThread(void * context)
{
    SOCKET socket = *(SOCKET*)context;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why not: (SOCKET)*param; , instead of * (SOCKET *)context; It is easier to read. Does it create warning otherwise? I don't compile on windows often ^^

Comment: Allright, thanks for answering. I've implemented this and now my _beginthread looks a lot neater without the casts. But the problem persists. I still receive random messages :/. I don't think it's a problem with a cast of the SOCKET as it's only just a number.

Comment: @Maresh: you cannot deference a `void*` pointer.  This has nothing to do with compiling on Windows.

Comment: @André, ye I figured that out after, since we don't know the size of the pointed object... But still i think it does work with gcc, i'll check.

Comment: @Maresh: Given `void* p`, `*p` is not a valid expression in C or C++, period.  There is nothing to dereference!  If it works for any compiler you know of, report it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
(void *)&sd
```

and

```
void receiveThread(void *param)

SOCKET sd = *(SOCKET *)param;
```

I think it should fix it !

Edit:

Writing (void *)sd create a pointer to the adress of sd value, which is wrong, You need to create a pointer to the address of sd, so u write &sd, so you can get its value once you are un the thread function by dereferrencing it: SOCKET sd = (SOCKET)*param;

My english isnt that good, I hope u understood.

Comment: Nope, the same thing happens :/ SOCKET is not really an object. It's just a number.

Comment: Not quite, you need to fix the `receiveThread()` function to accept `void*` and cast back to `SOCKET*` and dereference that.

Comment: Interesting.  For the benefit of observers like me, who would like to learn from your answer without the exercise of compiling the OP's code, would you briefly explain why?

Comment: Yea I edited my post after, didn't notice at first reading sorry. @tbh, i edited for you ;)

Comment: @thb It's not clear if he is on a platform with sizeof(void *) == sizeof(SOCKET).  That was true in Win32, but don't 64-bit modes mix pointer sizes and integer sizes, rather than match?

Answer (score 0):

the program should read (sudo code):

```
 while(1){
 listen()
 newSD = accept()
 pthread_creat(newsd)
```

}

this will create a new new thread for each connection while leaving main running

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to try including WaitForSingleObject() before you close the socket in the main function.